# Клиент и сервер на android

Tags: android, java

У меня есть сервер (написан на java), работающий на localhost port. Клиент написан на Android. Клиент содержит массив нулей и единиц. Как сделать так, чтобы при нажатии, например, на поле с единицей на сервер отправился индекс этой ячейки со значением один, сервер обработал и выдал второму клиенту сообщение, например, "Привет!". Подскажите, пожалуйста, уже голову сломал, как это сделать. Заранее благодарен!

Comment: Сервер-серверу рознь. Никто кроме вас не знает что за сервер как он написан с каким протоколом он работает что посылает, что принимает. Темный лес. Будьте более конкретны

Answer (score 1):

Метод навскидку - реализуешь layout с нужными полями  (например, типа `TextView`), делаешь `Activity` для этого layout, реализующего `OnClickListener`. В методе `onClick()` реализуешь посылку значения id элемента и значение `*.getText()`. А сервер, приняв сообщение, создает новый интент с нужной логикой.